# Why does an unimportant feature has a big impact on R2 in XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, feature-importances, r-squared

I am training an XGBoost model, `xgbr`, using `xgb.XGBRegressor()` with 13 features and one numeric target. The R2 on the test set is 0.935, which is good. I am checking the feature importance by

```
for col,score in zip(X_train.columns,xgbr.feature_importances_):
    print(col,score)
```

When I check the importance type by `xgbr.importance_type`, the result is `gain`.

I have a feature, `x1`, whose importance seems to be 0.0068, not so high. `x1` is a categorical feature with a cardinality of 5122, and I apply `LabelEncoder` before training the model.

I remove this feature from training set, and retrain the model with the same hyperparameters and the same training-testing set. The R2 seems to have a big hit and falls down to 0.885.

Why does a seemingly unimportant feature have such a big impact?

Comment: What are (some of) the other feature importances, and how do their removal affect R2?

Comment: How do you measure feature importance? One reasonable measure is by how much the out-of-sample $R^2$ improves when you add the feature vs omit it or randomize/permute the values.

Answer (score 0):

With no more context, my main guess is that it is an effectt  not of the features but the metric you are using. Remember that $R^2$ is nondecreasing, so it will be greater or equal as you add more predictors

I can recommend to use another metric like mean squared error and repeat the model evaluation.

For reference check: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133089/why-does-adding-more-terms-into-a-linear-model-always-increase-the-r-squared-val

Comment: The question specifies "R2 on the test set", which doesn't need to be monotonic. And R2 is just a scaled mse, so switching to mse won't change the comparison.